# make (Mac)Vim display certain character as something else

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-plugin, vim-syntax-highlighting, fontforge

I want to configure vim to be able to display certain character `⇒` as something else `=>`.

Obviously the first character is a non-ascii character, while the second one is actually two characters.

I was looking into something similar to `listchars` but with more flexibility as I can specify the character as well as the conversion.

I only want to do this for visualization purpose, i.e. I don't want to edit the actual file.

Alternatively I was thinking of editing the font itself to display this character differently and then use this "modified" version of the font inside MacVim only. but it seems to be very complicated and never works with fontforge.

Is there's anything similar in vim/macVim?

Comment: There is something similar in vim, yes: the `conceal` options for syntax highlighting. Have a look at some examples on youtube. People usually use it for shortening text, but I don't see why you couldn't use it the other way around. Here's a plugin that uses conceal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=37rIbrdHKwM

Comment: @moopet concealing is awesome, solved my problem perfectly, the conceal level and cursor is a nice touch, I had to change the '=>' because I cannot really conceal one character with more than one character. but that's good enough for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *conceal* feature allows to display a [sequence of] character[s] as a different single character. This could be used to display `=>` as `⇒`, but unfortunately, not the other way around.

Likewise, modifying the font won't work; each character occupies exactly one display cell (well, except for double-width characters, but you can't just turn a single-width into a double-width one).

I'm not sure what your motivation is, but just imagine how confusing editing would become if you could address the single `⇒` (even in widened form) as two characters (but editing commands like `f` or `:s` would still see the single character).

The only way to achieve something similar is to do a `:%substitute/⇒/=>/g` when editing the buffer, and undoing that for `:write` (using `:autocmd`s), but I would recommend against it.

Comment: I had to change '=>' to something that is one character, but conceal worked perfectly for me, thanks for the elaboration.

Comment: Ah, great. Your motivation wasn't very clear from your abstract question. Be aware that conceal is a syntax highlighting feature, so if there's an underlying syntax / filetype, it might interact with that negatively (but that depends on the syntax itself).

Comment: FWIW if you edit/create a font, you can make a character glyph into whatever width you want. Glyph length is specified for each separately within the OpenType font spec.